# OCMock - "Unexpected Method Invoked" although stubbed

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

Here is the testing code:

```
id dataControllerMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[RAMImsakyaDataController class]];
[[[dataControllerMock expect] andReturn:dataControllerMock] alloc];
(void)[[[dataControllerMock expect] andReturn:dataControllerMock] init];
[[[dataControllerMock stub] andReturn:@"30.06 , 50.67"] getLocationTitle];
[self.viewController viewDidLoad];
XCTAssertTrue([self.viewController.title isEqualToString:@"30.06 , 50.67"], @"View controller title is wrong");
[dataControllerMock verify];
```

The problem is that the dataControllerMock causing a failure with "unexpected method invoked: getLocationTitle"! I do stub the method. And even if I change the stub to expect, same thing. When I breakpoint inside viewDidLoad, the mock is already there as expected yet it doesn't recognize the getLocationTitle method.

Update: here is the viewDidLoad code

```
NSString *location = [self.dataController getLocationTitle];
if (location == nil) {
    self.title = @"إمساكية رمضان ١٤٣٥ هـ";

} else {
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"إمساكية رمضان ١٤٣٥ هـ (توقيت %@)", location];

}
```

Comment: The test code looks good and should do what you want. I don't think we can say much more without also seeing the controller code for `viewDidLoad`. By the way, a more descriptive question title would be helpful.

Comment: Changed the title and added the viewDidLoad. It's getting me crazy actually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a different approach and use a partial mock?

```
RAMImsakyaDataController* realObject = [RAMImsakyaDataController new];
id partialObject = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:realObject];
[[[partialObject stub] andReturn:@"30.06 , 50.67"] getLocationTitle];
[partialObject viewDidLoad]; // Method under test
XCTAssertTrue([partialObject.title isEqualToString:@"30.06 , 50.67"], @"View controller title is wrong");
```

I find that trying to mock alloc can lead to difficult behavior.

**EDIT**

```
// In MyViewController
- (RAMImsakyaDataController*)dataController {
    if (!_dataController) {
        _dataController = [[RAMImsakyaDataController alloc] init];
    }
    return _dataController;
}

Then partial mock the VC and replace this method with one that returns your partially mocked data controller.
```

Comment: Well this is not a view controller, it's a data controller

Comment: Ah. So rather than alloc initing it in your VC, why not change its getter to alloc init it if it doesn't exist? Then you could partialMock this method.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that OCMock is failing to correctly mock the data controller's `+alloc` method so your view controller is using a real data controller instead of a mock.

I've had a difficult time mocking object creation. What I've ended up doing instead of trying to mock `+alloc` is putting testability stubs on the objects I want to test that create their dependencies, and then I can use a partial mock of the object under test to override the object creation. Like:

```
@implementation ViewController
  - (void)init {
    ...
    _dataController = [self newDataController];
    ...
  }

  - (DataController *)newDataController {
    return [[DataController alloc] init];
  }
@end
```

And then in my test

```
ViewController *underTest = [ViewController alloc];
id mockUnderTest = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:underTest];
id mockDataController = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[DataController class]];
[[[mockUnderTest stub] andReturn:[mockDataController retain]] newDataController];
underTest = [underTest init];
```